# How to display data in select box option using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I want to display data in select box option from ajax response.

here is my view file

```
<select class="form-control" name="vendor" id="vendor_list" required style="width: 159px;">
<option value="">Vendor 1</option>
</select>
```

Here is my ajax success function

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, value) {
        console.log(value);
        $('#vendor_list').append('<option value="'+ value.id+'">'+ value.vendor_name +'</option>');
        console.log(value);
    });
}
```

here is my ajax response json data

```
[{"vendor_name":"scscss"},{"vendor_name":"xzcdsfdx"}]
```

How to display value in select box.
giv me suggestion.thanks

Comment: What is your issue ? I see nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? This code looks fine. If there are multiple responses as shown in your ajax response code, adding the options using a loop.

Comment: I am getting following error--morris.js (line 79, col 15)
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e

Comment: Try running each on `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: well it's coming from `morris.js ` we don't even know what that is. I don't think we can help you with the shared code.

Comment: Are you sure the success function is called, and that the data returned is correct? The code you give here seems to work fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/2yXsL/3/

Comment: yes i am sure. success function is called, and that the data returned is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is with

```
$('#vendor_list').append('<option value="'+ value.id+'">'+ value.vendor_name +'</option>');
```

It will be much better if you create a option string & append it after entire `data` has been iterated

Since it is not possible to replicate the ajax , so I have directly use the ajax response

You can put the entire code inside success block , but you will not need `var x` because `data` will play role of `var x=[...]` in your case

```
var x = [{"vendor_name":"scscss"},{"vendor_name":"xzcdsfdx"}]
var _options =""
$.each(x, function(i, value) {
        _options +=('<option value="'+ value.id+'">'+ value.vendor_name +'</option>');
    });
$('#vendor_list').append(_options);
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqze7etL/)